# Simple way to prove that $e^{-x^2}$ doen't admit Laplace inverse trasform

Tags: laplace-transform

The question is already contained in the title. Is there any criterion that one can use to show this or is it necessary to apply Mellin's inverse formula and verify that the integral doesn't converge?